# why does it not call function floor2

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In my code I want to call the function `floor2` if the score is more than or equal to 10, and then the function should be called when the player touches the door.

Currently when the player overlaps with the door it does nothing. I have tried moving the if statement about but doesn't seem to do much. I think it's either the if statement mentioned above or the function `floor2` causing the error but its a logic error so can't be too sure on where it's coming from

Here is my code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 7</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: { y: 300 },
                debug: false
            }
        },
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };

    var player;
    var platforms;
    var cursors;
    var score = 0;
    var scoreText;
    var end;

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/l1.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'assets/stone.png');
        this.load.image('star', 'assets/wine.png');
        this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/skull.png');
        this.load.image('door', 'assets/door1.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/test.png', { frameWidth: 39, frameHeight: 56 });
        this.load.spritesheet('dead', 'assets/test2.png', { frameWidth: 39, frameHeight: 38.5 });
        this.load.audio("bgm",'assets/constantine.mp3');
        this.load.audio("bottle",'assets/bottle.mp3');

    }

    function create (score)
    {
        bgm = this.sound.add("bgm", { loop: true});
        bgm.volume = 1.5
        bgm.play();

        bottle = this.sound.add("bottle",{loop:false});
        bottle.volume = 0.05;
        
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
        
        door = this.add.image(50,550,'door');
        

        platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

        platforms.create(400, 568, 'ground').setScale(2).refreshBody();

        platforms.create(600, 400, 'ground');
        platforms.create(50, 250, 'ground');
        platforms.create(750, 220, 'ground');

        player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'dude');
        
        player.setBounce(0.2);
        player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        this.anims.create({
            key: 'left',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 1, end: 3 }),
            frameRate: 10,
            repeat: -1
        });

        this.anims.create({
            key: 'turn',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 0, end: 0 }),
            frameRate: 20
        });

        this.anims.create({
            key: 'right',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', { start: 4, end: 6 }),
            frameRate: 10,
            repeat: -1
        });

        this.anims.create({
            key: 'dead',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dead', { start: 0, end: 1 }),
            frameRate: 10,
            repeat: -1
        });

        cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);

        stars = this.physics.add.group({
         key: 'star',
         repeat: 11,
         setXY: { x: 12, y: 0, stepX: 70 }
        });

        stars.children.iterate(function (child) {

           child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.4, 0.8));

        }); 

        this.physics.add.collider(stars, platforms);
        this.physics.add.overlap(player, stars, collectStar, null, this)

        scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'score: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000' });

        bombs = this.physics.add.group();

        this.physics.add.collider(bombs, platforms);

        this.physics.add.collider(player, bombs, hitBomb, null, this);
        
        if (score >= 10)
        
        {
            this.physics.add.overlap(player,door,floor2(score));
        }
      

    }

    function update ()
    {
        if (cursors.left.isDown)
        {
            player.setVelocityX(-160);

            player.anims.play('left', true);
        }
        else if (cursors.right.isDown)
        {
            player.setVelocityX(160);

            player.anims.play('right', true);
        }
        else
        {
            player.setVelocityX(0);

            player.anims.play('turn');
        }

        if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down)
        {
            player.setVelocityY(-330);
        }
    }

    function collectStar (player, star)
    {
        star.disableBody(true, true);

        score += 10;
        bottle.play();
        scoreText.setText('Score: ' + score);

        if (stars.countActive(true) === 0)
        {
            stars.children.iterate(function (child) {

                child.enableBody(true, child.x, 0, true, true);

            });

            var x = (player.x < 400) ? Phaser.Math.Between(400, 800) : Phaser.Math.Between(0, 400);

            var bomb = bombs.create(x, 16, 'bomb');
            bomb.setBounce(1);
            bomb.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
            bomb.setVelocity(Phaser.Math.Between(-200, 200), 20);

        }
        
        
    }

    function hitBomb (player, bomb)
    {
     this.physics.pause();
 
     player.setTint(0xff0000);

     player.anims.play('dead');
    
     end = this.add.text(300, 300, 'game over', { fontSize: '64px', fill: '#808080' });
     
     gameOver = true;
    }

    function floor2(score)
    {

        
       this.physics.pause()
       win = this.add.text(300, 300, 'you win', { fontSize: '64px', fill: '#808080' });
       gameOver = true;
        
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is what the game looks like
[image: the game display]

Comment: Not possible to know just by looking at your code. I would suggest using `console.log(score)`. Also add a `console.log` inside `floor2` to see if it gets there.

Comment: Cannot test so maybe you just forget to add semicolon `;`  for  `this.physics.pause();` on floor 2

Answer (score 0):

In Phaser, the `create` is run once when the game scene is created.

In your create you're setting up the scene and then checking if the score is 10 or more. The player hasn't played the game yet, so their score will be 0, so `this.physics.add.overlap(player,door,floor2(score));` isn't run.

At this point the `create` function is done, and won't be called again, so it'll never check whether the score is 10 or more, and therefore will never add that overlap call.

There's a number of things you could do instead. A few ideas:

1. Add a check when collecting bottles (`collectStar()`).
2. Add a check in `update()`.
3. Add a function to handle score changes, and check then.

However you implement it, you'll need to check the score outside of `create`.